# Does the Linux Mint installer include an option to replace/upgrade ONLY Linux Mint on a dual boot system?

Tags: linux-mint, dual-boot, upgrade

I have a dual boot system running Windows 7 64-bit and Linux Mint 16 (with Cinnamon).

I'd like to replace Mint 16 with Mint 17 (I'm OK with completely wiping JUST Mint).  I want to leave Windows just like it is.

Does the Linux Mint installer include an option that basically says "yeah... we're going to replace your old linux mint install but not touch anything else."

I thought there was something for this but the release notes for Mint 17 says:

```
In the installer, "Replace OS with Linux Mint" means erase the entire drive

If another operating system is present on the disk, the second option suggested by the installer is to "replace the OS with Linux Mint".

This option doesn't just wipe the partition used by the mentioned OS, but the entire drive and all its partitions.

For more information on this issue please visit: https://bugs.launchpad.net/linuxmint/+bug/1325786
```